# How to prompt the user for a variable number of values

Tags: c#, methods

Recently learned about params and what to use it for in methods, I created this one:

```
public int add(params int[] args)
{
    int Total = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
    {
        Total += args[i];
    }

    return Total;
}
```

I can call it just fine like

```
int Add = n.add(2,34,4,5,6);
int Add2 = n.add(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);

Console.WriteLine(Add);
Console.WriteLine(Add2);
```

But what If I want to pass it an unknown amount of user input?

Something like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(n.add(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()),Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())));
```

The problem is that this way I have to write `Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());` a bunch of times.

Is there any better way to do it? Like if the user types in 3 numbers it will sum them up, but if next times the user types in 5 number it will sum that up instead....etc, etc.

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you are asking here.  Your add function takes in an array of int so you should be just fine passing in any number of parameters.  If you want to minimize the amount of converts you need to pass the parameters to your add function in you could have your add function accept an array of string and parse to int inside your for loop in your add function.

Comment: Are you wanting the user to enter something like `12 5 24 17` and then produce the total?  That's a different scenario than the answers you are currently getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like what you want to do is to let the user enter the numbers while the program runs, and stop when the user is "done".  You would have to have some sort of exit condition.  Either the user enters "=" or something that tells the program that the user is done entering numbers to be added.

```
int Sum=0;
string s="0";
while (!s.Equals("=")) {
    Sum += Convert.ToInt16(s);
    Console.Write("Type a number (Enter = to get the sum): ");
    s = Console.ReadLine();
}
Console.WriteLine("The sum is " + Sum.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

A `params int[]` array argument will take either a series of `int` arguments, or else a single *array* of `int` (this is analagously true of `parmas object[]`, etc. etc.). So you can pass your `add(params int[] args)` method an array of ints of any size:

```
var a = new [] { 1, 2, 3 };

add(a);
```

In practical terms, this is how you'd use that for your case. You can add any number of ints to a `List<int>`, and then convert it to an array:

```
List<int> ints = new List<int>();

while (true) {
    var s = Console.ReadLine(s);

    int n;
    if (Int32.TryParse(s, out n)) {
        ints.Add(n);
    } else {
        break;
    }
}

int sum = add(ints.ToArray());
```

But here's how I'd sum that list of ints instead:

```
var sum = ints.Sum();
```